# Android: styling overflow menu in action bar

Tags: android, menu, styles, overflow

I am using v7 support library in my project. My manifest settings are:

```
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

I used Android Action Bar Style Generator to generate styles for my Action Bar. The problem is that while everything works for the newest apis, my **overflow menu** does not change in low apis (tested on emulator 2.2 and real device 2.3.3 htc desire).

[image: 1]

(this should have red background)

Is menu overflow loading items in some other component like spinner dialog or        something (sry if that sounds dumb) ? Why styles for one api(ex 15) doesn't apply for other(ex 8), and is there anything i can do to have same overflow menu for all api versions.

This is my original generated style from Action Bar Style Generator which i tweaked a lot but with no success.

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
<style name="Theme.yourapp" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.yourapp.Widget</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.yourapp.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, the `android:` namespace pertains to anything built into the OS while anything without `android:` as the namespace would pertain to your application (and the libraries you are using). Most, if not all, support libraries for the `ActionBar` will try to use the native ActionBar implementation and therefor use the `android:` namespace attributes in your styles. When the native ActionBar is not available it would use the libraries implementation and the non-`android:` namespaced attributes. This is why you must specify every attribute with and without the `android:` namespace.

Comment: actually i did. with no effect though.. i lost couple of hours to find that clearing lint markers removes the warning eclipse gave me. can you specify the attributes which needs writed again with android: namespace.. maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you using the right directories? you should have at least `values`, `values-v11` with android namespaced attributes in `values-11`.

Comment: well, i have two values directories generated by AB style generator.
values and values-v14. in values attributes are used without android: namespace and in values-v14 WITH android: